# conditionally replace values in next row

Tags: r, data-manipulation, recode

How can I write a conditional function that compares entries in rows of a data frame in R. For example if entry in row 1 is greater than entry in row 2 replace row 2 entry with "lower"

```
row1 row2
667  668    
673  674
665  679 
664  668
```

Entries in first column will be higher,lower,lower if the function is applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ifelse`:

```
dat$row2 <- ifelse(dat$row1 < dat$row2, "higher", "lower")
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do

```
dat1 <- dat
dat1[] <- c('lower', 'higher')[t(apply(dat, 1, order))]
```